# Multiple enemies don't follow player - Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I do an RPG that enemies follow the player. When I duplicate enemies, only one follow he.

All enemies do the action of run (they move his arms and legs), but don't move of his destination (only one follow player).

I think the problem comes from navMeshAgent, only one is shared for all enemies.

```
public float lookRadius = 10f;

Transform target;
static NavMeshAgent agent;
CharacterCombat combat;

public float timeLlegadaE = 10f;

public float velocidadAtaque;
private float attackCooldown = 0f;

bool ataque = false;

void Start()
{
    target = PlayerManager.instance.player.transform;
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    combat = GetComponent<CharacterCombat>();
    attackCooldown = velocidadAtaque;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    attackCooldown -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (timeLlegadaE < 0)
    {
        ataqueFalse();

        float distance = Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position);

        if (distance <= lookRadius)
        {
            if(agent != null)
            {
                agent.SetDestination(target.position);

                avanzarTrue();

                if (distance <= (agent.stoppingDistance) && attackCooldown <= 0)
                {

                    ataqueTrue();

                    //anim.SetBool("Atack", false);
                    //Debug.Log("Interacting with " + transform.name);

                    FaceTarget();

                    attackCooldown = velocidadAtaque;
                }
                else if (distance <= (agent.stoppingDistance) && attackCooldown > 0)
                {
                    avanzarFalse();
                }
            }

        }

        lookRadius = 150f;
        gameObject.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().enabled = true;

    }
    else
    {
        timeLlegadaE -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
static NavMeshAgent agent;
```

is [`static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) => basically "shared" between all instances of this script so in

```
agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
```

you overwrite this value for all instances.

Why is this `static` at all? simply make it

```
[SerializeField] private NavMeshAgent agent;

private void Start()
{
    if(!agent) agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    ...
}
```

and if possible already assign it via the Inspector.